# Arraylist doesnot add userinput in java

Tags: java, arraylist

The purpose of this program is to print out a message saying 'you missed' each time a coordinate is entered.However,if a duplicate coordinate is entered,it should say 'This coordinate is already present.'

I used 2 arraylists simultaneously,to independantly store the values of x and y.I fail to understand what is wrong with my code.The if statements don't seem to be working at all and the userinput also doesnt seem to be added to the arraylists.

```
Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);

//Arraylist stores all entered x values.
ArrayList<Integer> XValues=new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Arraylist stores all entered y values.
ArrayList<Integer> YValues=new ArrayList<Integer>();

int Nooftries=0;
int xcoord;
int ycoord;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Nooftries++;
    System.out.println("This is guess #"+Nooftries);

    System.out.print("Please input your x location (0-3) : ");
    xcoord=a.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please input your y location (0-3) : ");
    ycoord=a.nextInt();

    XValues.add(xcoord);
    YValues.add(ycoord);


    for(int c=0;c<XValues.size();c++)
    {

        if(xcoord==XValues.get(c) && ycoord==YValues.get(c))
        {

            System.out.println("You've already picked that spot.\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You missed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try and evaluate if the user has input a given cell AFTER you've already added the values

Comment: I am sure they are other data structures that suite your goal out there

Comment: http://junit.org/  <--- your new best friend.

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
XValues.add(xcoord);
YValues.add(ycoord);
```

And *then* you check. Since you've added the most recently input values, of course your arrays will contain those values when you check afterwards.

You'll want to check *before* adding. Alternatively you could just check up to `XValues.size() - 1`, but doing the check before adding more clearly reflects your intent.

The `if` statements *are* working; your program is simply doing precisely what you told it to do. You just need to tell it to do the right thing!

The rest of your logic looks fine at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `xcoord` and `ycoord` into the array lists right before the `for` loop, so of course the `for` loop will spot them and show `You've already picked that spot`. You should add them after the `for` loop.